# Queued job shows completed but did not execute method of event listener

Tags: cakephp, queue, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP(3.6) Events for sending email on a certain action. And want to use queue for differed action.
I have integrated  [Queuesadilla](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-queuesadilla)  plugin for this purpose and using **MysqlEngine**.

Mostly I have followed  this  blog https://someguyjeremy.com/2017/07/queued-events-in-cakephp.html  .

I have started the worker by executing this command.

> $ bin/cake queuesadilla

Event has been queued and cleared after a certain time (suppose delay is 10 sec). But the method which is supposed to be called after dispatch , is not being called. 
But   it says

> Success. Acknowledging job on queue

.

I have a separate listener.Here it is.

```
namespace App\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;
use Cake\Log\Log;
use App\Queue\QueueManager;

class TestListener implements EventListenerInterface
{
    public function implementedEvents()
    {
        Log::write("debug","inside listener");

        return [
            'Controller.Reports.afterRemove' => 'afterRemove',
        ];

    }

    public function afterRemove($event)
    {

        Log::write('debug', "Test listener has been fired");
    }
}
```

I don't understand why **afterRemove()** method was not called ? 
And  I want to send Email from this method but it looks like it's not being called !

And this is how I have enqueued the job

```
 $test = [
             1=>"Test message"
         ];
          $event = new Event('Controller.Reports.afterRemove', null,$test);

          QueueManager::queue($event, [
              'delay' => 10
          ]);
```

Here how I have attached my listener with global

```
 use App\Event\TestListener; 
 use Josegonzalez\CakeQueuesadilla\Queue\Queue; 
 Configure::load('queuesadilla', 'default', false); 

 Queue::setConfig(Configure::consume('Queuesadilla'));
 $testListener =new TestListener();
 EventManager::instance()->on($testListener);
```

Am I missing something ? Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code where you add your TestListener to the Event Manager?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's very unreadable, instead update your question - thank you! Also I suggest that you add the information and findings that you discussed with Jeremy Harris on this, it may help others to spot the problem.